# Google OAuth 2.0 not working for Google Workspace (G Suite) Accounts

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have created a project at Google Developer Console. And I have followed the steps to create an OAuth Consent screen to ask users for their consent to let me use their email address and Google Calendar for my App. App is still at Test Mode, and everything is working fine.

But for the users of Google Workspace (G Suite) (@domain.com) the consent screen is not working. It just ends up saying that **Something went wrong** and **... the request is malformed...**. I am sure it isn't malformed, because it is just working fine for non-workspace (@gmail.com) users.

I got it working later by **Manage Domain Wide Delegation** by logging into the Google Workspace Admin account and manually setting up my Apps's service account Client ID and Scopes. The process allowed users of that @domain.com (non-admin) email to get my consent screen working.

But this is not practical. I can't ask every @domain.com email address user to contact their Google Workspace Admins and add my app to the domain wide delegation area manually.

There are apps and services out there which connected to my non-admin Google Workspace account without having my Admin do it for me.

So there must be some way to get my consent screen work on @domain.com email addresses hosted at Google Workspace without involving the Admin account or Domain wide delegation stuff.

How can I get it done? Please help, I can't find any solution online.

**EDIT** More banging head in the wall, but no similar issues found on the internet. So what I feel like is that I need to wait for my OAuth application to be approved for production for it to work for Google Workspace accounts. PLEASE HELP if you know there is some other issue and I can try to fix...

Thanks.

Comment: `App is still at Test Mode` Since it is in test mode, have you added test users for this app? I assume the app domain and the domain of these users is not the same one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was some temporary issue with Google. I emailed them, and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Hi @arxoft, I am dealing with the same problem as you. Did you email the system admin or the google supporter. In my system, it seems the system admin added a Google Workspace panel after login with the google account.

Comment: @tandathuynh148 I just replied to the email I received from *API OAuth Dev Verification* email I received from Google.

Comment: The IT administrator changed some configurations to solve the issue